# x509 Certificate value Base64 encode not correct output in PHP

Tags: php, base64, x509, cert

I am trying to encode base64 for my certificate and the code I am using this:

```
include('phpseclib1.0.20/File/X509.php');
$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('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');
echo "Signature Base64: " ;

echo base64_encode($cert['signature']);
```

the output I got:

```
QURCR0FpRUE3bUhUNnlnODVqdFFHV3AzTTd0UFQ3SmsyK3pzdlZIR3MzYlU1WjdZRTY4Q0lRRDYwZWJRYW1Zall2ZGVibkZqTmZ4NFg0ZG9wN0xzRUJGQ05Tc0xZMElGYVE9PQ==
```

But the correct output should be this:

```
MEYCIQDuYdPrKDzmO1AZanczu09PsmTb7Oy9UcazdtTlntgTrwIhAPrR5tBqZiNi915ucWM1/Hhfh2insuwQEUI1KwtjQgVp
```

How can I get the correct output?

Thanks for all

Comment: I think `$cert['signature']` is already base64 encode because I can double decode what you [posted](https://3v4l.org/T9UZY). The binary output doesn’t match your expected however.

Comment: @ChrisHaas actually you are right, but the correct output should be like this: `H0F!�a(<;Pjw3OOdQƳv!�jf#b^nqc5x_hB5+cBi` if you noticed the difference is `H`

Comment: Your posted version doesn’t begin with an `H` either? https://3v4l.org/Sj6iP

Comment: @ChrisHaas but why when I use ```MEYCIQDuYdPrKDzmO1AZanczu09PsmTb7Oy9UcazdtTlntgTrwIhAPrR5tBqZiNi915ucWM1/Hhfh2insuwQEUI1KwtjQgVp``` the QR encoded reult is correct but with this ```QURCR0FpRUE3bUhUNnlnODVqdFFHV3AzTTd0UFQ3SmsyK3pzdlZIR3MzYlU1WjdZRTY4Q0lRRDYwZWJRYW1Zall2ZGVibkZqTmZ4NFg0ZG9wN0xzRUJGQ05Tc0xZMElGYVE9PQ==``` the QR encoded not correct!

Comment: just to be notice this result ```MEYCIQDuYdPrKDzmO1AZanczu09PsmTb7Oy9UcazdtTlntgTrwIhAPrR5tBqZiNi915ucWM1/Hhfh2insuwQEUI1KwtjQgVp```  is coming from C# code

Comment: The version that starts with a Q, which is double-base64 encoded, has a leading `00` which might be a null byte: https://3v4l.org/8HvZc

Comment: @ChrisHaas very good notice! do you think the issue from the PHP X509 library, the resolution should omit the ```00``` ?

Comment: Looking at the source, there's at least [one specific comment](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/d39777128aaa1baba492fa339b28e77c1ba9bff4/phpseclib/Crypt/EC/Formats/Keys/PuTTY.php#L104) about a null byte as it relates to PuTTY, and there's a [test](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/e2a20a6ad99e01357ca26fcfc318dab157d3a699/tests/Unit/Crypt/EC/KeyTest.php) that accounts for it a bunch of times, too. Also, the [x509 source](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0/phpseclib/File/X509.php) has `\0` in it several times.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the spec to know if this is hack to fix a specific implementation, or if byte alignment is required, or something else. For your purposes, however, I think you would be safe trimming the leading null byte since that gets you back to a signature that you already know works.